# Project Server 2010 Beta - can't connect Project client to projects hosted on server

Tags: sharepoint-2010, microsoft-project

We have a Project 2010 Beta installed on SharePoint 2010 Beta as test set-up whilst we wait for the release versions.

Whilst the installation seemed to complete without any issues we're  unable to open any projects within the Project 2010 client app.  Project pops up an error 'Could not retrieve server initialization data'.  My local event logs list some errors from MSSOAP that simply state an unanticipated error occurred during the processing of the request.  The server doesn't log any errors.

The Sharepoint set up is a farm containing 3 SharePoint servers. I log in to server 'PORTAL' but the Project Server stuff is configured to run on one of the other SharePoint boxes.

I presume others have managed to get this working - has anyone got any ideas as to what could be wrong.  Everything is patched correctly as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well - the answer in my case was to chalk this off as a quirk of the Beta.  Both Project Server and the underlying SharePoint were the Beta 1 versions.

I've since re-installed with the RTMs of each product and whilst I've still had smaller headaches during the install (and a couple still outstanding) this specific problem is now resolved and the client app can at least connect up to Project Server and enumerate all the project files that are listed up there.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to do this:  http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/896861?p=1

I just followed Method 1 and it worked for me.